# For loop over variable name in Octave

Tags: octave

I am applying transformations on a column by column basis to a matrix, the problem is that this transformation will not affect each column equally, leaving me with a collection of different length columns. I want to further iterate over these columns but cannot find the way to word it in Octave.

```
for v = 1:6
    gate_values( 1, (2*v)   ) = C(1, v);
    gate_values( 1, (2*v)-1 ) = t(1);

    for i = 1 : (length(C) - 1)
        if C( i+1, v ) - C(i, v) > 0.05  % Taken as 10% of bin value
            gate_values( i+1, (2*v)   ) = C( i+1,v );
            gate_values( i+1, (2*v)-1 ) = t( i+1 );
        endif
    endfor
    t_imp = toc
endfor 

gate_values_1(:,1)= nonzeros( gate_values(:, 1) );
gate_values_1(:,2)= nonzeros( gate_values(:, 2) );
gate_values_2(:,1)= nonzeros( gate_values(:, 3) );
gate_values_2(:,2)= nonzeros( gate_values(:, 4) );
gate_values_3(:,1)= nonzeros( gate_values(:, 5) );
gate_values_3(:,2)= nonzeros( gate_values(:, 6) );
gate_values_4(:,1)= nonzeros( gate_values(:, 7) );
gate_values_4(:,2)= nonzeros( gate_values(:, 8) );
gate_values_5(:,1)= nonzeros( gate_values(:, 9) );
gate_values_5(:,2)= nonzeros( gate_values(:,10) );
gate_values_6(:,1)= nonzeros( gate_values(:,11) );
gate_values_6(:,2)= nonzeros( gate_values(:,12) );
```

The nonzeros function means the columns will be different lengths so i cannot simply populate a matrix this way, would there be a way to create these gate_value columns by iterating for example I have tried (among variations).

```
for k=1:6
    gate_values_k(:,1) = nonzeros( gate_values(:,1) );
```

but this causes an error (for reference I'm assuming this is possible as in vba i could write gate_values_ & k to achieve this). Thanks.

Comment: Please share more details about the error you are getting, this will help the community to understand your use case and share the relevant solution. Feel free to refer StackOverflow Q&A guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Numerical arrays generally do not allow you to have columns of different lengths. Obviously if your columnwise operations involve a "zero element" with regard to that operation, you could simply pad your columns with that zero element.

Otherwise, you are probably looking for ['cell arrays'](https://octave.org/doc/interpreter/Cell-Arrays.html) instead. Presumably you can create a cell array where each cell contains a vector (of non-equal length to all others), and then use something like arrayfun, cellfun, accumdim / accumarray etc (depending on the exact operation you're trying to perform) to perform aggregate operations across the cells.